# Pythagorean triples and Pell's equations

Tags: pell-type-equations

We all know that Pythagorean triples are diophantine equations of order 2. So my question is can the solutions to **ALL** Pell's equations of the form $X^2-DY^2=1$ be derived from the Pythagorean triples? Is there an algorithm to do it?

P.S: I found an interesting paper (details below) that deals with the solubility of negative Pell's equation in terms of Primitive Pythagorean Triples. I was wondering if an algorithm be derived from it for even the normal Pell's equations.

A. Grytczuk, F. Luca and M. Wójtowicz, “The Negative Pell Equation and Pythagorean Triples"

Comment: Yes and yes.  See https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Yang.pdf for instance.

Comment: I am sorry, but that paper has no relation between Pythagorean triples and Pell's equations. I know how to solve a Pell's equation using simple continuous fractions but I wonder if there is a shortcut using Pythagorean triples.

Comment: The Pythagorean triples are found by generating the rational points on the curve $x^2+y^2 =1$.  You can put a $D$ in there and do the same thing, if you like.

Answer (score 4):

Pythagorean triples correspond to the special case of rational solutions for $D=-1$ and relate to rational points on the unit circle.

If $X^2+Y^2=1$ then $(X^2-Y^2)^2+(2XY)^2=(X^2+Y^2)^2=1$ and $X^2-Y^2$ and $2XY$ give another solution.

The Pell equation is looking for integer points on $X^2-DY^2=1$. Once one solution is found note that $(X^2+DY^2)^2-D(2XY)^2=(X^2-DY^2)^2=1$ so that $(X^2+DY^2)$ and $2XY$ make a further solution.

Note that there are finitely many integer points on the unit circle - $(0, \pm 1)$ and $(\pm 1, 0)$ while the group of rational points is not finite and not finitely generated (geometrically there are rational points at arbitrarily small angles with the real axis).

On the other hand for Pell's equation, which is looking for integer points, and with positive $D$ (negative $D$ is trivial), the group generated by the solutions is finitely generated (though an infinite abelian group: if solutions exist - we can always generate more as above). The existence of a fundamental unit from which all solutions can be derived is the interesting result in this case - and that is the productive approach.

You know, as you comment, the continued fraction methods here. If you read the literature you will see that fundamental solutions can be surprisingly large in relation to $D$. It would be a real surprise if something as simple as deriving solutions from Pythagoras would work as a general procedure - how would you account for this phenomenon?

---

Just to note, on the new solutions from old theme:

If $X^2-DY^2=1$ and $W^2-DZ^2=1$ then we can consider $$(X+Y\sqrt D)(W+Z\sqrt D)=(XW+DYZ)+(XZ+YW)\sqrt D$$ and we find that $$(XW+DYZ)^2-D(XZ+YW)^2=(X^2-DY^2)(W^2-DZ^2)=1$$

This works in the Pythagorean case for $D=-1$

Comment: I know that for the negative Pell's equations to be soluble, then a Primitive Pythagorean triple satisfying a certain criterion should exist as given in this paper \\

A. Grytczuk, F. Luca and M. Wójtowicz, “The Negative Pell Equation and Pythagorean Triples". 

So I was thinking maybe something similar for normal Pell's equation exist. I agree that for certain values of $D$, the solutions can be very large like $D=97$.

Comment: @WilburWestwood Always useful if you have references to cite them in the actual question - the first theorem is that the Pell equation $X^2-DY^2=1$ is solvable ifff there is a primitive Pythagorean Triple $A^2+B^2=C^2$ and positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $D=a^2+b^2$ and $|aA-bB|=1$. Then (second theorem) $X=|aA+bB|, Y=C$ is a solution of the Pell equation. So this enables them to build Pell solutions from primitive Pythagorean Triples - but they don't show how to hit a specified value of $D$. If this is your question, please sate it more fully.

Comment: I understand the need of references. But I found it after I posted the question. So it was not in the original Q. I will emend it now. Also it is for the Pell equation of the form $X^2-DY^2=-1$ not the normal Pell's equation.

Comment: @WilburWestwood The $-1$ version of the Pell's equation is not so different. There is still a "fundamental unit" for which odd powers give $-1$ solutions and even powers give $+1$ solutions - if you look at the identities I gave you will see how two $-1$ solutions (possibly he same) can be combined to give a $+1$ solution.